# Angular cordova app , redirect to app after third-party OAuth

Tags: angular, cordova

I have an angular web app, which on the landing page by clicking on login redirects to third-party OAuth service.

I have wrapped my angular app with Cordova as follows [Followed [this](https://medium.com/@christof.thalmann/convert-angular-project-to-android-apk-in-10-steps-c49e2fddd29) post]:

- change href to "./" and added cordova.js script tag in src/index.html.
- changed  angular build output to www from dist.
- then, ng build --prod --aot.
- Cordova build android.

The app installed without any errors.

**The Problem**

The app shows landing page fine but as soon as I click on login, it opens up chrome and never redirects to the app but continues the journey in chrome itself.

**My Understanding**

- I understand that since I have not used any in-app browser, android opens up the default browser for the HTTP calls.
- But, if I use an in-app browser then, the journey complete journey might be continued in the in-app browser itself.

How do I make the redirects to be rendered in the app itself?